# append data to quill editors existing data angular

Tags: angular, editor, quill, ngx-quill

I am working on a requirement where I have to append data to a container that is quill-editor container in angular. I tried different things but neither they worked.

I tried below:

**Try-1**

```
this.mailTemplateForm.controls['body'].patchValue(value)
```

**Try-2**

```
this.mailTemplateForm.controls.body.setValue(value);
```

**Then the existing data is getting replaced by the new data**. What is the solution for this.

component.ts:

```
import { QuillEditorComponent } from 'ngx-quill';
export class EditMailTemplateComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild('description') description: QuillEditorComponent; 
 mailTemplateForm: FormGroup;

 ngOnInit() {
  this.getFormData();
 }

 editForm(){
//console.log('test',this.data);
this.mailTemplateForm = this.fb.group({
  id: 0,
  name: [''],
  slug: [''],
  status: [''],
  subject: [''],
  body: [],
  body_parameters: [''],
 });
}

getFormData(){
  -----------
  -----------
  this.editForm();
  this.mailTemplateForm.patchValue(this.data.form_data);
}
appendTagTo(value: any){
  console.log('called - ',value);
  this.mailTemplateForm.controls.body.setValue(value); // Tried here
}
```

**component.html**

```
<ul class="list-style-none mt-0">
   <li *ngFor="let field of fieldList" class="py-4 text-uppercase">
     <a color='accent' class='cursor-pointer' (click)="appendTagTo(field.field_name)"> {{ field.label_name }}
     </a>
   </li>
</ul>

<div fxFlex="75" class="mt-12">
  <quill-editor [style.display]="'block'" [style.height]="'400px'" formControlName="body" #description>
  </quill-editor>
</div>
```

I want the data to be added wherever the cursor presents inside the quill-editor (or) if the cursor not there in the editor at the starting point. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps someone. I have solved it by using registering quill-editor's 'onEditorCreated()' method like below:

```
<quill-editor [style.display]="'block'" [modules]="editorOptions.editor"
      (onEditorCreated)="onEditorCreated($event)" [style.height]="'300px'" formControlName="body" #description>
    </quill-editor>
```

**component.ts**:

```
public editor;

onEditorCreated(event) {
 this.editor = event;
}

appendTagTo(textTOInsert: string) {
 if(textTOInsert){
  textTOInsert = '{{'+textTOInsert+'}}';
  const selection = this.editor.getSelection(true);
  this.editor.insertText(selection.index, textTOInsert);
  //this.editor.insertHTML(selection.index, textTOInsert);
 }
}
```